# Test class has an runtime error

Tags: apex, unit-test

Test class throw the runtime error

> System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception

```
public with sharing class LWCExampleController {
   
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void deleteRawData(list<Id> lstRawIds){
        try {
            list<Raw_Data__c> lstRawToDelete = new list<Raw_Data__c>();
            System.debug('lstRawIds ====> '+lstRawIds);
            for(Id idRaw : lstRawIds) {
                lstRawToDelete.add(new Raw_Data__c(Id = idRaw));
            }
            if(!lstRawToDelete.isEmpty()) {
                delete lstRawToDelete;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Raw_Data__c> retrieveRawData(){
        system.debug('Inside retrieveRawData method:   ' + ([SELECT Id, Name, Salary__c FROM Raw_Data__c limit 1000]) );
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Salary__c FROM Raw_Data__c limit 1000];
    }
   
}
```

Test class

```
@istest
public class LWCExampleController_Test {
    static testMethod void test() {
        LWCExampleController.deleteRawData(new List<Id>{
            '0012w00000Eb8SMAAZ',
                '0012w00000FeAJfAAN'
        });
        LWCExampleController.retrieveRawData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create test data for Raw_Data__c object. Then pass the ids in the deleteRawData method. Refer https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_data to create test data for your test class.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you can just call `Database.delete` with a list of record ids as a parameter, no need to instantiate SObjects at all (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

Comment: I've downvoted because this is a code dump. It doesn't contain a question (though it's implied that you want help in resolving the error) and doesn't show any effort to research/solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks aakriti I solved that using to create test data for my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be expected, and I'd go so far as to say it's *good*.

You're getting the exception because you're trying to delete records *that do not exist* in your test.

You are responsible for creating the data required for your test (except for "setup objects" like `User` and custom metadata type records).

While you could fix this issue and get this test method to run, I'd argue that you still want this scenario (trying to delete records that don't exist) as a test method. Best practice for testing is for us to test both positive cases (input is well-formed and what you expect) *and negative cases* (input is bad and will cause issues).

This case where you try to delete records that don't exist is a fine example of a negative case.

Also, you should be making assertions to verify the results of your test (things like checking that records were actually deleted or that an exception has been thrown).

Coverage without assertions is useless. You could have 100% coverage of a method that tells you that the result of 2 + 2 is 5 and be able to deploy it, but you'd be deploying something that is obviously wrong and broken.

The primary goal of testing is to verify that your code is working correctly. Coverage is a side-effect, and will naturally be high if you have enough test methods which test different possible scenarios.